# How to compile classes to JDK1.5 when ant is running in JDK1.6

Tags: compilation, backwards-compatibility, java-6, java-5

My development environment is running in JDK1.6, and I need to compile some classes so they are compatible with a client running JDK1.5.  How would I do this with the 'javac' ant target?

Answer (score 3):

Command line : javac -target 1.5 sourcefiles

Ant: `< javac srcdir="${src} destdir="${build}" target="1.5" />`

Comment: Just tried this solution and got a warning that I also needed to set source="1.5", other than that this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
<javac source="1.5"... />
```